# Mat expansion panel is opened by default bug?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Since Angular 5 release, I have some problem with my mat expansion panels. They are opened by default and I don't understand why.

my html

```html
<div *ngFor="let block of blocks; let i = index;">
<mat-expansion-panel *ngIf="selectedIndex == 2" (closed)="onClosed(i)" (opened)="onOpened(i)" [expanded]="expansionPanelIndex === i">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
           ....
        </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>
           ...
        </mat-panel-description>
     </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
</div>
```

in my component

```js
    tabChanged(tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
        this.selectedIndex = tabChangeEvent.index;
    }

    onOpened(i) {
        this.expansionPanelIndex = i;
    }

    onClosed(i) {
      this.expansionPanelIndex = -1;
    }
```

EDIT : I updated Material to 5.1.1 same problem
EDIT 2 : I had a "selectedTabIndex" in my tab-group

```
<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex" (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
...
<mat-expansion-panel ...>
</mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The two way binding wasn't a good idea here. But now, I have another problem (click on nextStep button doesn't do anything)

Comment: What do you need the `expansionPanelIndex` for? Is it, because you want not more than one panel to be opened at a time?

Comment: Yes that's it. I think I found my problem. I edited my first post.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem.

It was about this : *ngIf="selectedIndex == 2". I replaced it by a boolean which is updated when I change tab (MatTabChangeEvent)

```html
    tabChanged( tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent ): void {
        this.selectedIndex = tabChangeEvent.index;

        if (this.selectedIndex == 2) {
            this.displayBlock = true;
        }
        else {
            this.displayBlock = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: (closed) and (opened) methods are not supported in production build.

Answer (score -2):

(closed) and (opened) methods are not supported in production build.
Better to add something like following is better.

```
          <mat-expansion-panel
          #expPanel>

          <mat-expansion-panel-header
            (click)="changeActiveIndex(expPanel.expanded, i)">
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: I don't know with version of angular are you using but it's working for me (5.2.10).